# Can I ask for review of a design proposal?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I recently published a formal proposal and request for feedback for what is probably the most significant extension to APL's syntax ever.

Would it be on-topic to ask for feedback on the proposal?

Comment: What kind of feedback? General "Is this good / Can this be improved" questions seem too broad and/or opinion-based, but questions about the pros and cons of specific parts of the proposal may be on-topic.

Comment: @DLosc Really any and all. Maybe I missed something, e.g. internal inconsistency, or potential problems in usage if implemented as proposed.

Answer (score 1):

Asking for feedback on a specific aspect of your proposal is definitely fine. For example, questions like these could definitely be on-topic:

- "Does this syntax extension introduce any ambiguities in the grammar?"
- "Would it be feasible for an extension of language X to implement feature Y?"
- "How can I ensure that my syntax extension will not conflict with syntax introduced by other third-party extensions?"

Notice that these are all **questions** which can be answered.

On the other hand, *"please give me any and all feedback on this syntax proposal"* is not a question, it is a **request**. If you try to phrase it as a question, it becomes something like *"what design, implementation or usability issues are there with this design proposal?"* ─ and this is too broad. The same would apply on pretty much all Stack Exchange sites except [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

General feedback requests are more suited for discussion forums; particularly since it is a proposal for extending a particular language, I would say it's best to ask for feedback in a community of people who use or develop that language. Some languages even have a formal process (e.g. [JEPs](https://openjdk.org/jeps/0), [PEPs](https://peps.python.org/pep-0000/), or the [TC39 process](https://github.com/tc39/proposals)) which involves community feedback; this may not apply to proposals for third-party extensions, but the communities around those processes may still be able to offer feedback.

Comment: What I said but better written :)

Answer (score -1):

### Opinion based but a good fit

Feedback is inherently opinion based but to my mind this should be an excellent forum to solicit feedback on a modifications to a language.

I think we should allow them if the focus of the proposal is sufficiently narrow.

I should also add that [r/ProgrammingLanguages](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammingLanguages) is a good place to solicit feedback in either case.